# Excel file with multiple row of column headers and blank columns in Data Factory?

Tags: excel, azure-data-factory

I have an Excel file as source in Data Factory which has multiple rows for column headers and blank columns as separators. May I know what would be the best approach to transform this dataset into a single dataset?

[image]

My idea is to make it like:

Header 1 Subhead 1
Header 1 Subhead 2
Header 2 Subhead 3
Header 2 Subhead 4

But I don't know how to realize it :(

Also I have blank columns which I delete manually in Select function. Is there any way I can select columns in the Dataset options?

Comment: Look for the common item in both sets of data. Then combine using that. Don't know how to suggest any more as you show so little.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to skip lines, so just skip 2 lines on the copy activity with excel as the source. Then you can manually name the fields in the mapping tab of the copy activity according to your want (Header1 sub1, Header1 sub2, Header2 sub1, Header2 sub2, etc). I’ll post a picture tomorrow, but that should work for you.